# Control panel UI/UX Ubuntu 23.04 Gnome 44 looks strange each install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome-shell

Notice the rounded corners?

[image]

[image]

Yet they are both fresh downloads from Ubuntu.com, tried to update and update but doesn’t seem to correct the strand issue, plus the whole background apps thing only works with the one install instead of the other, apt get upgrades/update full update, flat packs, snaps, kernels,,,, they dont really cut, and the issues seem strange.

Comment: is the issue `the rounded corners` - is that what looks strange?

Comment: Yea, why is that, same install exact update - the one with the g one 43 look doesn’t do the background apps for some reason… it’s weird, each install has its own way of doing thing, both installed offline too.